# Usage of global vs. constant memory in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda

Hey there,
I have the following piece of code:

```
#if USE_CONST == 1
    __constant__ double PNT[ SIZE ];    
#else
    __device__ double *PNT;
#endif
```

and a bit later I have:

```
#if USE_CONST == 0
    cudaMalloc((void **)&PNT, sizeof(double)*SIZE);
    cudaMemcpy(PNT, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
#else
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(PNT, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE);
#endif
```

whereas `point` is somewhere defined in the code before. When working with `USE_CONST=1` everything works as expected, but when working without it, than it doesn't. I access the array in my kernel-function via

`PNT[ index ]`

Where's the problem between the both variants?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably a case of accessing out of bounds. Uninitialized constant memory is set to 0, where as it is undefined in global space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct usage of cudaMemcpyToSymbol prior to CUDA 4.0 is:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("PNT", point, sizeof(double)*SIZE)
```

or alternatively:

```
double *cpnt;
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&cpnt, "PNT");
cudaMemcpy(cpnt, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

which might be a bit faster if you are planning to access the symbol from the host API more than once.

EDIT: misunderstood the question. For the global memory version, do something similar to the second version for constant memory

```
double *gpnt;
cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&gpnt, "PNT");
cudaMemcpy(gpnt, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE.  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice););
```

Comment: Okay, first thanks. The strange thing is that it works eben without the quotation... But what I asked for was rather the access when not having `USE_CONST=1`, which means that the block with the global memory is used... `__device__ double *PNT;` etc... Than it doesn't work correct :( Is there anything wrong about it?

Comment: talonmies' answer for how to do it is correct (so I upvoted), but it lacks an explanation.  The explanation is: `*PNT` is a `__device__` variable, not a host variable containing the address of a device variable. (Confusing, I know.) Therefore if you try to access it on the host as with `(void**)&PNT` you are trying to read a device variable from the host which is not permitted.  From the host code point of view it's just a symbol, so you need to use `cudaGetSympolAddress()` to store the device address in a host variable that you can then pass to `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`, as @talonmies shows.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good explanation :) And thanks @talonmies too :)

Comment: For future readers: The string version is deprecated, that is why the version without the quotation marks works (and is prefered). The usage as shown here wont work correctly! The usage of `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` already uses `cudaGetSymbolAddress` so using it twice will break

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question I add this for future googlers:

The problem is here:

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&PNT, sizeof(double)*SIZE);
cudaMemcpy(PNT, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The `cudaMalloc` writes to the host version of `PNT` which is actually a device variable that must not be accessed from host. So correct would be to allocate memory, copy the address to the device symbol and copy the memory to the the memory pointed to by that symbol:

```
void* memPtr;
cudaMalloc(&memPtr, sizeof(double)*SIZE);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(PNT, &memPtr, sizeof(memPtr));
// In other places you'll need an additional:
// cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&memPtr, PNT, sizeof(memPtr));
cudaMemcpy(memPtr, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Easier would be:

```
#if USE_CONST == 1
    __constant__ double PNT[ SIZE ];    
#else
    __device__ double PNT[ SIZE ];
#endif

// No #if required anymore:
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(PNT, point, sizeof(double)*SIZE);
```